# Django list not using css

Tags: css, django, list, models

Hi I have a problem with using css for a list that prints all the objects for a model from a database. I can't seem to change the fontsize used for each item in the list

subtemplate file

```
{% extends 'template.html' %}
{%block title %} View Music Packs {% endblock%}
{%block header %} View Music Packs {{page_name}}{% endblock%}

{% block body_block %}
<div id = "subtemplate">
<ul>
    {% for musicpack in object_list %}
        <li>
            {{musicpack.title}} - {{musicpack.composer}} - {{musicpack.arranger}}
        </li>
    {%empty %}
        <li> No musicpacks yet. </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

section of css

```
#subtemplate{
background: grey;
width :70%;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top: 20px;
border: solid orange 3px;
}

#subtemplate ul{
list-style-type: none;
font-size: normal 20px;
}

#subtemplate ul li{
font-size: normal 20px;
}
```

template.html section

```
<div id="main_section">
<h3> {%block header %} Template {% endblock %} </h3>

{% block body_block %}
This is just an empty Template
{% endblock %}

</div>
```

I suspect that there is something I'm missing as I have used to this when just working with html only files and it works fine.

Comment: can you copy the rendered html and post it as well

Comment: edit: added to question

Comment: none of the answers below worked hmm so strange

Answer (score 0):

`font-size` only takes **one** property so instead of using

```
font-size: normal 20px;
```

Use

```
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: normal;
```

or

```
font: normal 20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nd87C/)

```
 font-size: normal 20px;
```

is not proper css syntax

```
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 20px
```

do it like this instead

Answer (score -1):

The font-size propierty doesn't admit that propierty

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp

So try with:

```
#subtemplate ul{list-style-type: none;font-size: 20px;}
#subtemplate ul li{font-size: normal 20px;}
```